# node.js syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: node.js

I have an SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input. I'm new to Node. The error is on line 33 at }). I'm pretty sure it either has to do with the closing of a function but not quite sure.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/favorites', function(req, res){
  var data = fs.readFileSync('./data.json');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(data);
;

app.get('favorites', function(req, res){
  if(!req.body.name || !req.body.oid){
    res.send("Error");
    return
  
  var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json'));
  data.push(req.body);
  fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(data));
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(data);
};

app.list(3000, function(){
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: yes, you're missing the close brace and parenthesis for `app.get('/favorites'`. Look for the line that just has a `;` on it. It should be `});`

Comment: Same thing for `app.get('favorites'` actually (the second one). The `};` actually belongs to the if statement. Maybe you actually want to close that if right after the return, i suspect so. In that case you'd add that brace after the return, and then you'd need to add a close parenthesis after the brace and before the semicolon.

Comment: if you've got visual studio code or some other visual editor, most of them will have a "format selection" or "format document" option...this might be helpful to you. It will indent things correctly based on your braces etc, and you'll see right off if you're missing a closing brace because all the code after it won't be indented.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to close off the parenthesis for 2 get request 
here:

```
app.get('/favorites', function(req, res){
    var data = fs.readFileSync('./data.json');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(data);
});  //here
```

and here:

```
app.get('favorites', function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.oid){
    res.send("Error");
    return

    var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json'));
    data.push(req.body);
    fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(data));
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(data);
}); //here
```

Comment: you missed one...he also didn't close his `if` block in the second code section you've quoted